# how to set multiple effect on same gpuimageview

Tags: java, android, filter, effects, android-gpuimageview

i am trying to put a sticker on a  gpuimageview and apply the effects on it by gpuimagefilter
first,when i tried to apply a new effect on previous effect of gpuimage it ignore the previous effect and apply the current one, but i want this effect to apply on the previous effect.

second is when i tried to  capture the bitmap from the gpuimageview by capture();
method and save it to the sd card it shows only gpuimageview but i want also to capture the sticker  which is on the gpuimageview. sticker are of the object of image view type
please help me out.sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved by this:

```html
gpuImageView.setImage(gpuImageView.getGPUImage().getBitmapWithFilterApplied(bitmap));
```